# Azure Logic App report success when HTTP action fails

Tags: azure-logic-apps

## Problem

I have a http action in my logic app that returns a `404` error when the item being checked isn't found in the database. This is by design, I expect to see a lot of `404` errors. I have no control over the API so I can't adjust what's returned in the response or the code returned. The run after is configured and dependent actions succeed

Due the `404` being returned my logic apps report as failed, and this throws off the reporting.

Is there a way to mark the action as succeeded if the response code is 404?

## Logic app flow

[image: Logic App Flow]

## Failure History

[image: Failure History]

Comment: please share the endpoint which you are trying to access here

Comment: Endpoint is Have I been pwned:
`GET https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/{account}`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a Scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't observe this behaviour. Are you sure no other action fails in your workflow down the line?

[image]

You can try using the [`Terminate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#terminate-action) action with `Status` = `Succeeded`, although I haven't encountered a scenario yet where this would have been useful.

**Update**: In your screenshot, I noticed that you're using a loop. Have you made sure that all 4 iterations in this loop succeeded? The 'Create UPN' could have failed in one of the iterations, or there could have been other issues.

Comment: Create UPN wasn't failing. The scope for the run after on error is what I needed. Thank you